# EventhubReceiver: Inconsistent messages received

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Issue: While calling EventhubReceiver.ReceiveAsync() method in rapid succession, the receiver does not receive all the messages in the event hub. The sample code that is used to receive events.
Note: the offset passed to the method is "0" across multiple calls

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EventData>> GetMessagesAsync(string messageOffset, int maxCount)
    {
        var receiver = await GetEventHubReceiver(messageOffset);

        return await receiver.ReceiveAsync(maxCount);
    }
```

Is there any inherent checkpoint with the receive call that needs to be taken into account? A different approach perhaps?